# i want help to change product page in prestashop 1.7.5.1

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I use Prestashop 1.7.5.1.
I want the description block and product details on the product page to be on the right side of the page and also fill the entire width of the page. How can I do this? What changes should be made to the product.tpl file or to the corresponding CSS file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to assist you because you did not post a fiddle with your HTML/CSS code, please try to edit/update your question.

However, I'm assuming you are using the default template coming with PrestaShop 1.7.x so you should have two columns with the class "col-md-6" inside your product.tpl file.

Simply put `style="float:left;"` on the one containing the product picture and `style="float:right;"` on the other.

Regarding the width of these columns, there are currently constrained by the  element:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1140px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

You can for the width to 100% with `width: 100%;` instead, I wouldn't recommend doing this though.

**Final result:**

[image: New CSS]